# ¿Como puedo solucionar este problema de sincronía?

Tags: javascript, asincronismo

tengo  esta linea de código que recibe la información de una determinante y a través de la misma busca los datos para llenar una tabla, el problema esta en que aveces arroja resultados y aveces no los encuentra me comentaron que es un problema de sincronía pero la verdad no encuentro el error.

El erro esta en la información que debe arrojar dentro de las tablas, que aveces si arroja datos pero en ocasiones no encuentra ningún dato.

Me comentaron el uso de Async y await, para ejecutar de manera asincrona una funcion pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema solo que un poco menos frecuente.

```
function HeaderData(props){
  const { data } = props, classes = useStyles(true);
  const [drawer, setDrawer] = useState(false);
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({mts:[], files:[]});

  const items = [
    {title:"Determinante", field: "DET"},
    {title:"Formato", field: "FORMATO"},
    {title:"Unidad", field: "UNIDAD"},
    {title:"CEDIS", field: "CD"},
    {title:"Estado", field: "EDO"}, 
    {title:"Exedente", field: "EXE"},
    {title:"Frecuencia semanal", field: "CYCLE"},
    {title:"Patio HUB", field: "HUB"},
    {title:"Venta", field: "VENTA"},
    {title:"Chep", field: "CHEP"},
    {title:"Notas de Cargo", field: "notes"},
  ];


   async function getDataStore(store){
    const status_store =  await request.getStoreStatus(store);
    await setInfo(status_store); 
}

     useEffect(()=>{
       getDataStore(data.DET);
    },[]);


  return(

    <div className={classes.headers}>
    <Toolbar style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
    {
      items.map((think) => {
        if(data[think.field] || data[think.field] === 0 || think.field ==='chep' ){
        return(
            <ListItemText 
            primaryTypographyProps={{
              variant:"subtitle2"
            }}
            secondaryTypographyProps={{
              variant:"body2",
              style:{
                color:"#fff"
              }
            }}
            primary={think.title} 
            secondary={think.field === 'CHEP'? Boolean(data[think.field]) === true ?"CHEP":"WALMART": data[think.field]}/>
        )
      }
      })
    }
    <ListItemText 
      primaryTypographyProps={{
        variant:"subtitle2"
      }}
      secondaryTypographyProps={{
        variant:"body2",
        style:{
          color:"#fff"
        }
      }}
      primary="Ocupabilidad" secondary={`${parseInt(props.space)}%`}/>
    <Tooltip title="Mostrar status de tienda">
      <IconButton
      className={classes.iconbutton}
      onClick={() => setDrawer(true)}>
        <MoreVert/>
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
    </Toolbar>
    <MaterialTable
            title= "Ultimo TCE"
            data= {info.files}
            options={{
              header:false,
              paging:false,
              search:false,
              maxBodyHeight:50
            }}
            columns={settings.sequemaTables.Files_Travels}/>
    <SwipeableDrawer
    open={drawer}
    onClose={() => setDrawer(false)}
    anchor="bottom"
    PaperProps={{
      style:{
        margin:"10px",
        borderRadius:"5px",
      }
    }}>
      <List>
        <ListSubheader>
          <Toolbar>
            <div className={classes.title}>
            <Typography className={classes.spacing}>
              Status Detetarminante
            </Typography>
            </div>
            <div style={{flexGrow:1}}/>
            <IconButton 
            onClick={() => setDrawer(false)}>
              <Clear/>
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
        </ListSubheader>
        <ListItem>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <MaterialTable
            title={
            <div className={classes.title}>
                <Typography 
                variant="subtitle2"
                className={classes.spacing}>
                  Viajes Anteriores
                </Typography>
            </div>
            }
            data={info.files}
            options={{
              paging:false,
              search:false,
              maxBodyHeight:350
            }}
            columns={settings.sequemaTables.Files_Travels}/>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Card>
            <MaterialTable
            title={
            <div className={classes.title}>
            <Typography 
            variant="subtitle2"
            className={classes.spacing}>
              Notas de cargo
            </Typography>
            </div>
            }
            options={{
              paging:false
            }}
            components={{
              Toolbar: propers => (
                  <div>
                    <MTableToolbar {...propers}/>
                    <Divider/>
                    <Toolbar>
                    <ListItem>
                      <ListItemAvatar>
                        <Avatar>
                          0
                        </Avatar>
                      </ListItemAvatar>
                      <ListItemText secondary="Notas de Cargo"/>
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem>
                      <ListItemAvatar>
                        <Avatar>
                          0
                        </Avatar>
                      </ListItemAvatar>
                      <ListItemText secondary="Folios"/>
                    </ListItem>
                    </Toolbar>
                    <Divider/>
                  </div>
              )
          }}
            icons={{
              Filter:FilterList,
              FirstPage: FirstPage,
              Search: Search,
              Clear:Clear,
              PreviousPage: KeyboardArrowLeft,
              NextPage: KeyboardArrowRight,
              LastPage: LastPage,
              Export:SaveAlt,
              Edit:Edit,
              Check:Check,
              ResetSearch:ClearOutlined,
            }}

            columns={[
              { title: 'Nota de Cargo', field: 'file' },
              { title: 'Determinante', field: 'det' },
              { title: 'Proveedor', field: 'provider' },
              { title: 'Costo', field: 'Costo' },
            ]}/>
          </Card>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <MaterialTable
            title={
            <div className={classes.title}>
                <Typography 
                variant="subtitle2"
                className={classes.spacing}>
                  Despachos MTS
                </Typography>
            </div>
            }
            data={info.mts}
            options={{
              paging:false,
              search:false,
              maxBodyHeight:350
            }}
            columns={settings.sequemaTables.MTS_Store}/>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </SwipeableDrawer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Buenas, de momento se me ocurre que los useState van primero de todo según documentación. Lo segundo es que await setInfo(status_store); no hace falta await. Si a veces no recibes datos revisa que tu API devuelva esos datos para ello con F12 viendo las llamadas debería valer.

Comment: Gracias implementare las observaciones, al revisar la consola arroja este error.

Comment: 0.chunk.js:291953 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at main.chunk.js:1068

Comment: Pues yo revisaría la función getStoreStatus, a ver que estas haciendo ahí, ya que se ve que tienes un problema con lo que estas devolviendo.